# Blessed List Failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I am trying to make a simple listbox.

```
var blessed = require("blessed");

// Create a screen object.
var screen = blessed.screen();

// Create a box perfectly centered horizontally and vertically.
var serverList = blessed.list({
    align: "center",
    mouse: true,
    width: "50%",
    height: "50%",
    top: "center",
    left: "center",
    items: [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four",
        "five",
        "six",
        "seven",
        "eight",
        "nine",
        "ten"
    ]
});

// Append our box to the screen.
screen.append(serverList);
serverList.select(0);

// Quit on Escape, q, or Control-C.
screen.key(["escape", "q", "C-c"], function(ch, key) {
    return process.exit(0);
});

// Focus our element.
serverList.focus();

// Render the screen.
screen.render();
```

According to the docs and [`chjj/blessed/test/widget.js`](https://github.com/chjj/blessed/blob/98b931be7f72a795c0c229f373f0bc997a9f2eae/test/widget.js#L60) that should be all I need. But it just errors out saying it can't read hight. Here is the error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of null
    at ScrollableBox.Element._getTop (/home/giodamelio/Projects/real/Vindinium-Bots/node_modules/blessed/lib/widget.js:2595:17)
    at ScrollableBox.Element._getBottom.parent [as top] (/home/giodamelio/Projects/real/Vindinium-Bots/node_modules/blessed/lib/widget.js:2617:15)
    at Box.Element._getTop (/home/giodamelio/Projects/real/Vindinium-Bots/node_modules/blessed/lib/widget.js:2613:17)
    at Box.Element._getBottom.parent [as top] (/home/giodamelio/Projects/real/Vindinium-Bots/node_modules/blessed/lib/widget.js:2617:15)
    at Screen._focus (/home/giodamelio/Projects/real/Vindinium-Bots/node_modules/blessed/lib/widget.js:1439:19)
    at Screen.focusPush (/home/giodamelio/Projects/real/Vindinium-Bots/node_modules/blessed/lib/widget.js:1389:8)
    at Screen.clearRegion [as focused] (/home/giodamelio/Projects/real/Vindinium-Bots/node_modules/blessed/lib/widget.js:1467:15)
    at ScrollableBox.Node.insert (/home/giodamelio/Projects/real/Vindinium-Bots/node_modules/blessed/lib/widget.js:86:25)
    at ScrollableBox.Node.append (/home/giodamelio/Projects/real/Vindinium-Bots/node_modules/blessed/lib/widget.js:95:8)
    at ScrollableBox.List.add.List.addItem.List.appendItem (/home/giodamelio/Projects/real/Vindinium-Bots/node_modules/blessed/lib/widget.js:4262:8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug in `blessed`. If you manually specify `parent: screen` in the `blessed.list()` options, it will work. For some reason it's not automatically determining the parent.

The reason the test you linked to works is because there are other widgets added to the screen first, which means the list will definitely have its `parent` set (to the previously added widget).

Comment: Thanks, I will go file a report.